# Can Exchange create catch-all addresses for address.*@domain.com?

Tags: exchange

I'm not an Exchange expert, and want to see if something is feasible before I ask for this. I'm looking for two things: 1) Is this possible? 2) Is there a better way to do this?

I want to have a catch-all address setup, but I need it to act differently than a typical catch-all address. To illustrate what I need:

1) address@domain.com
2) address.*@domain.com
3) address.123@domain.com
4) address.abc@domain.com

I want to setup an email address (1). That address should catch anything meeting the criteria in (2) where the . is literal, the * is wildcard. For example, both (3) and (4) should direct to (1), because they meet the criteria of (2).

The reasoning for this is we have a need to create a large number of unique email addresses that only need to receive email. We cannot rely on the default catch-all email address, because this is a smaller scope than what the default catch-all would see. We would have a few users granted access to (1) so they could monitor inbound emails when needed. We have hundreds of users who need to assign things to a certain, unique email address, and cannot feasibly create new addresses for each item.

I'm not asking for the rules to create (although if anybody knows off the top of their head, awesome), but rather is this possible in Exchange 2007/2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this.  It is actually called a 'catch-all mailbox'.

What you will do is create a new mailbox, then create the rules you want to foward to this mailbox on your hub transport server.

More details here...
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691132(v=exchg.80).aspx

There are a lot of rules you can use to forward messages as you need on the hub transport server in your Exchange manager.

It is also possible that what you are looking for is just to create your address@domain.com mailbox and create aliases for the other email addresses to send into this same mailbox.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - that's exactly what I needed to know!

Comment: You'll also need to configure the SMTP domain as an "internal relay domain", as opposed to an authoritative domain; otherwise, Exchange will reject all messages addresses to non-existent users before even starting to process the transport rules.